# Windbg for memory analysis using mimikatz ERROR [CRYPTO] acquire keys

Tags: windbg

I'm using windbg version 6.12 and using mimilib.dll for debugging memory. All works fine until I get following output on UI

```
0:000> !mimikatz

DPAPI Backup keys
=================

Current prefered key:       

Compatibility prefered key: 

SekurLSA
========
[ERROR] [CRYPTO] Acquire keys
```

note: the memory dmp is of `lsass`

Is this anything to do with symbol or respective dll /system32? Kindly suggest.

Comment: Maybe you want to try a newer version of WinDbg like 6.3 http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/

Comment: Since you're asking if this could be a symbols issue: what do `lm` and `.sympath` say about symbols?

Comment: @Thomas thanks, i'm using windows 7 that's why can't update.

Comment: @Thomas no error for ".sympath"

Comment: but the underscore o/s should be Win 8 how did you install on win 7? I tried it give me SDK error

Comment: @Thomas updated successful after installing .net 4.5 but error is the same

Answer (score 0):

I was using WinDbg x86 where x64 was required.